Define GPIO name/status in Device Tree and have it accessible from userspace
I have a custom board with several GPIO. I'd like to:

give them a friendly name
be able to get the level at boot time
define active high/low

I defined the GPIO as hogs like this
&gpio5 {
    ext_gpio_2 {
        gpio-hog;
        gpios = <26 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        input;
        line-name = "ext_gpio_2";
    };
};

With this, I set the GPIO direction at boot and have the correct name listed when I call gpioinfo gpiochip4. The problem is that the GPIO is labeled as [used], and I get Device or resource busy error when trying to get its level.
How can I avoid the [used] status and be able to control the GPIO?
